# worksheet object not defined, code works in one sheet but not another

Tags: excel, vba

This sub is designed to control the colour of the cell adjacent to a checkbox when it is ticked without the checkbox object being linked to a cell. In the old version of the sheet the identical code works exactly as intended. When applied to a new workbook however it fails on the line in bold with the error code below:

> Run time error '1004'

> Method 'Checkboxes' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Do I need to define the worksheet elsewhere in my code or is this an issue with the application caller? Entirely possible its something else but I don't know how the same code that works in one book fails in another.

```
Sub ItemReturn()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lColD As Long
Dim lColChk As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rngD As Range
Dim lRowChk As Long

lColD = -1 'number of columns
lRow = 0
Set ws = ActiveSheet
**Set chk = ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)**
lRow = chk.TopLeftCell.Row
lColChk = chk.TopLeftCell.Column
Set rngD = ws.Cells(lRow, lColChk + lColD)
Select Case chk.Value
   Case 1   'box is checked
        rngD.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Case Else
        If IsEmpty(rngD) = False Then rngD.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End Select

End Sub
```

I've tried:

1. renaming the worksheet Dim
2. heading straight to an activesheet without a Dim statement
3. removing the application caller from the line of code

Comment: It appears that ws.CheckBoxes(..) is a Function that accepts a parameter. Apparently it's in some module of the original book. You must also copy it into a module in the new book and everything else that is called through it... If The ws.CheckBoxes is exactly as is... it means that the Function is in the sheet's module.

Comment: `Worksheet.CheckBoxes()` is a hidden function that accepts a checkbox index and returns the checkbox. [What `Application.Caller` may return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller#remarks) does not seem like an index of a checkbox. How is `ItemReturn` called in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll start combing through the old sheet for what's missing here. I believe the sub is activated on use of a checkbox if that helps clarify. @GSerg

Comment: Your code will only work if you run it by **ticking the check box** while you have previously **assigned the macro to the check box**. Otherwise, `Application.Caller` will be something like `Error2023` and the code will fail. Right-click the check box and select `Assign Macro...` ...

Comment: @GSerg There doesnt appear to be any reference to the sub or a CheckBoxes object elsewhere in the sheet. I'm having to adapt a predecessors work so i really dont know much of how this precisely runs yet

Comment: Really is a Worksheet's hidden function and works ONLY with form controls, non with ActiveX checkboxes.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Looks like I missed a sub called checkboxlink which may be the culprit

Comment: It would be nice of you to share the *"sub called checkboxlink"* which is hopefully assigning the macro to all the checkboxes so future readers could see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

### Run Code By Ticking Any Check Box (Forms Control) in a Worksheet

[image]

- As I stated in the comments, the macro needs to be assigned to each check box for `Application.Caller` to return the name of the check box and the code to work.
- While playing around with it, I came up with the following. It covers some of the surprises you may encounter.
- Remove or out-comment the `Debug.Print` lines when done playing.

```vb
Sub ItemReturn()
     
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Item Return"
     
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = -1
    Const COLOR_INDEX As Long = 22
     
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox """" & ActiveSheet.Name & """ is not a worksheet.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim CheckBoxName: CheckBoxName = Application.Caller
    
    If IsError(CheckBoxName) Then
        MsgBox "This code is designed to run only when ticking a check box.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Worksheet Name: " & ws.Name
    Debug.Print "Check Box Name: " & CheckBoxName
    
    Dim chk As CheckBox
    On Error Resume Next
        Set chk = ws.CheckBoxes(CheckBoxName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If chk Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no check box named """ & CStr(CheckBoxName) & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Debug.Print "Check Box Value: " & chk.Value
        
    Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = chk.TopLeftCell
    
    Debug.Print "Top Left Cell Address: " & tCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim c As Long: c = tCell.Column + COLUMN_OFFSET
         
    If c < 0 Or c > ws.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "There is no column '" & c & "'.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = tCell.Offset(, COLUMN_OFFSET)
    ' the same as:
    'Set cCell = ws.Cells(tCell.Row, c)
    
    Debug.Print "Highlight Cell Address: " & cCell.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim DoHighlight As Boolean
    
    If Len(CStr(cCell.Value)) > 0 Then
        If chk.Value <> 1 Then
            DoHighlight = True
        End If
    End If
            
    If DoHighlight Then
        If Not cCell.Interior.ColorIndex = COLOR_INDEX Then
            cCell.Interior.ColorIndex = COLOR_INDEX
        End If
    Else
        If Not cCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            cCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Results for Check Box 1**

```
Worksheet Name: Sheet1
Check Box Name: Check Box 1
Check Box Value: 1
Top Left Cell Address: B1
Highlight Cell Address: A1
Worksheet Name: Sheet1
Check Box Name: Check Box 1
Check Box Value: -4146
Top Left Cell Address: B1
Highlight Cell Address: A1
```